# what word means "to show off my clothes"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means "to show off clothes", something like "parade".

> Working from home gives me the ability to show off my fancy pyjamas

Comment: [Thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/browse/show+off?s=t) gives (among others) *boast, brandish, demonstrate, display, disport, exhibit, expose, flaunt, make a spectacle of, parade, trot out,* any of which might fit, depending on the context of your sentence. This is General Reference, I think.

Comment: First word I thought of was _flaunt_; I agree with Andrew – a good thesaurus should to the trick from there.

Comment: Thanks, _flaunt_ did the trick. Add it as an answer and I'll chose it

Comment: @nachocab: *flaunting* normally implies *annoying others by your ostentatious display*, whereas you can (in principle) *sport* something even if there isn't actually anyone else around to see it. Certainly *sporting* has no significant implication of being tiresome to others - in fact, it's usually said admiringly. I think a good paraphrasing of *flaunt* is *to [rudely/irritatingly] wave [something] under other people's noses*, so it's not really appropriate in your context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Good point, but _show off_ as a phrasal verb can have that same overtone (i.e., one of deliberate pretentiousness), although it needn't carry that connotation. With so little context here, it's hard to tell whether the O.P. would have preferred to include or avoid that implication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working from home lets me **swan about, sporting** my fancy pyjamas.

> [swan [around/about]](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/swan_2) *to travel, move or behave in a relaxed way for pleasure and without worrying that others may feel annoyed*
>   [sport:](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&tbo=u&q=sport&tbs=dfn:1&sa=X&ei=3MjmUMXeLaWY1AXmrIDABg&sqi=2&ved=0CDEQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.d2k&fp=f42fee5d8e10998d&bpcl=40096503&biw=1343&bih=889) *wear or display (a distinctive or noticeable item) - he was sporting a huge handlebar mustache*.

Answer (score 2):

You have the ability to **display** your fancy pyjamas.

You need to be careful that some of the words suggested by a thesaurus may carry a negative connotation. In particular, if I say that you *flaunt* your possessions then I am suggesting that your display is rather vulgar and displeasing to me.

Comment: right, I meant it as a tongue-in-cheek comment